# Can Touch ID Work With a Windows 10 VM?

Tags: windows, high-sierra, virtualbox, touch-id

I checked, this is not a duplicate.

I just installed VirtualBox on my MacBook Pro (macOS HS 10.13.3).

So, Apple created "support software" that allow *special* hardware to be used in Windows 10. That means the Touch Bar, Fingerprint sensor for Windows Hello, etc.

Can Windows Hello be used in a VM?

Maybe through Windows Support Software?

Comment: Possible dup of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259061/how-will-the-new-touch-bar-touch-id-work-with-windows-boot-camp

Comment: It's not the same question. There the question is if Windows can use those devices when running directly on the macbook hardware. Here the question is if the VirtualBox virtual machine can emulate those devices and make them available to the guest OS.